# Is it correct to say that objects can display polymorphism

Tags: oop, polymorphism

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm#:~:text=Polymorphism%20is%20the%20ability%20of,is%20considered%20to%20be%20polymorphic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm#:%7E:text=Polymorphism%20is%20the%20ability%20of,is%20considered%20to%20be%20polymorphic).

As per the link above, in which they say:

> Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms.

I'm having trouble figuring out whether to take this literally or not.
From my knowledge of polymorphism, classes are polymorphic when they can have multiple children, each implementing a parent class method in a different way.
A function can be polymorphic as we can overload and override them so functions can display different behaviors.

I was told and taught that another form of polymorphism applies to objects  that inherit from multiple parent classes.
In C++ for example an object may behave differently depending on its reference type if its methods aren't virtual.
Another example that comes to mind is in Java with multiple interfaces, I can look at an object as different types causing different expected behaviors.
Are these examples really considered polymorphism at play or is this just inheritance and Polymorphism best defines the first two examples (classes and methods)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning of the word "polymorphism" is what the tutorial says. However it makes very little sense to use the literal meaning of a technical term. In OOP, "polymorphism" means [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). There are other ways the term "polymorphism" is used in programming (ad-hoc and parametric polymorphism) but they are not related to OOP specifically.

"Polymorphic object" is not a standard term across the OOP literature. It has a very specific meaning in C++, and it's *not* "an object with several base classes". It is simply an object with at least one virtual function. From the OOP perspective, a C++ "polymorphic object" is just an object.

Deriving from more than one base classes is called multiple inheritance. I have never heard anyone using the term "polymorphism" for this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)
From what I can find the literature has a few different perspectives on polymorphism that aren't just subtyping. If I can rephrase my question (made a small edit as well to try and make it clear) 

Pertaining to my examples subtyping is considered polymorphism that is derived from classes having multiple child classes.

Ad-hoc polymorphism is what I described with method overloading.

Is what I'm describing with objects considered a type of polymorphism? Or are my teachers just confusing Multiple Inheritance and Polymorphism

Comment: @crommy added more info to the answer